# Sentry get CORS error in localhost by VueJS3

Tags: vuejs3, sentry, vite

I'm using http://localhost:3000 to development my website, but I always get CROS error from Sentry, what am I missing?

in Sentry's Setting:
I've set the project's Allowed Domains to *, but it's looks like not work....

**Access to fetch at 'my-sentry-dsn' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Vue3 + Vite

```
yarn add @sentry/tracing @sentry/vue
```

in main.ts

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/vue"
import { Integrations } from "@sentry/tracing"
const app = createApp(App)
// Initialize Sentry
const dsnSentry = import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_DSN as string
if (!!dsnSentry) {
  const env = import.meta.env.VITE_ENV
  const isDebug = env !== "production"
  Sentry.init({
    app,
    dsn: dsnSentry,
    // integrations: [new Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
    integrations: [
      new Integrations.BrowserTracing({
        routingInstrumentation: Sentry.vueRouterInstrumentation(router),
        tracingOrigins: ["localhost:3000", /^\//],
      }),
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
    debug: isDebug,
  })
}

app.mount("#app")
```

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem by using `*` in the `tracingOrigins` param.

Like this:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "__DNS__",
  integrations: [new BrowserTracing({ tracingOrigins: ["*"] })],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});
```

Another problem, can be ads block extension like adblock, ublock.

Comment: omg I was going crraaazzzyyy with CORS, this was it!

Comment: do note tracingOrigins option doesnt exist anymore https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/master/packages/tracing/src/browser/browsertracing.ts#L170

Comment: @ihor.eth, what is the alternative? Thanks!

Comment: @ddsultan no idea I removed tracing altogether since I dont need it, the docs are kind of vague about this.

Comment: the alternative may be `tracePropagationTargets` but use as the top level option in Sentry.init()


`Sentry.init({
  app,
  dsn: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SENTRY_DSN,
  environment: import.meta.env.MODE,
  tracePropagationTargets: ['*'],  <--- this
...`

Comment: In my case uBlock was blocking the requests..