# How to fix Sentry Angular App Receiving CORS error

Tags: angular, sentry

I'm running an angular app with versions

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.11
Node: 18.16.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 13.4.0
```

I'm receiving this response from Sentry `{"detail":"event submission rejected with_reason: Cors"}` when POSTing `https://xxxxx.ingest.sentry.io/api/xxxxxxx/envelope/?sentry_key=xxxxxxxx&sentry_version=7&sentry_client=sentry.javascript.angular-ivy%2F7.66.0`

I'm developing locally on `localhost:4200`

I've set the allowed domains in sentry project settings to allow my localhost access via:

```
localhost:4200
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any guidance.

EDIT to show initializing in main.ts:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import {AppModule} from "./app/app.module";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/angular-ivy";

Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://xxxxx@xxxxx.ingest.sentry.io/xxxxx",
    tracePropagationTargets: ["localhost", /^https:\/\/xxxxxxxx.ngrok-free.app/],
    integrations: [
        new Sentry.BrowserTracing(),
        new Sentry.Replay({
            maskAllText: false,
            blockAllMedia: false,
        }),
    ],
    // Performance Monitoring
    tracesSampleRate: environment.production ? 0.2 : environment.staging ? 0.5 : 1.0, // Capture 100% of the transactions, reduce in production!
    // Session Replay
    replaysSessionSampleRate: environment.production ? 0.1 : environment.staging ? 0.5 : 1.0, // This sets the sample rate at 10%. You may want to change it to 100% while in development and then sample at a lower rate in production.
    replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0, // If you're not already sampling the entire session, change the sample rate to 100% when sampling sessions where errors occur.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to allow "localhost" in the "Allowed Domains" setting inside your project settings.

Comment: I started out with this and it doesn't work. The only thing that works is setting * in allowed domains. I don't want that so I just uninstalled sentry. Moving on without it.

Comment: Strange choice for sure but your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to allow `localhost` in your Sentry configuration because that is not a unique FQDN. The sentry servers also have `localhost`, and your machine is not exposed to the internet. You need a domain (or IP address) that is exposed to the internet.

If you have a cloud instance e.g. on AWS, you can run the application on it and use the server IP address instead. You can also investigate domain/serverless options such as Cloudflare Workers or Firebase.

Another recommendation is to forward your local port to a domain. e.g. using https://ngrok.com/, which will tunnel requests to that domain to your machine.

This will generate a domain such as `http://123456789.ngrok.io` that you can put in your Sentry config instead.

Next, you need to tell Sentry that the request is coming from this server, so you can add a `HOST` header etc, which might be too hacky for you.

Comment: I setup ngrok and it still returns a 403 CORS

Comment: Can you share how you are initializing Sentry? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804069/sentry-get-cors-error-in-localhost-by-vuejs3

Comment: made the edit to show init

Comment: What version of sentry-javascript are you using?

Comment: @sentry/angular-ivy@7.66.0

Comment: It works if I set Allowed Domains to *

Comment: Try setting your "allowed domains" to `localhost` instead of `localhost:4200`. A valid "domain" shouldn't include the port, so that could be it, as seen in this example https://forum.sentry.io/t/event-submission-rejected-with-reason-cors/10389